# counting unique combinations of object properties

Tags: java

I have a class `TypesHolder` that has four properties which are each `int` values.  I want to identify how many unique combinations of values are in the four int variables, and then to give a count of how many instances of `TypesHolder` have each specific combination of the four integer variables.  **How can I accomplish this in code?**  My code attempt below is failing, with the failed results summarized at the end.  There must be a simpler way to do this correctly.

Here is my `TypesHolder` class:

```
public class TypesHolder {
private int with;
private int type;
private int reason1;
private int reason2;
    //getters and setters
}
```

To hold the unique combinations during analysis, I created the following `TypesSummaryHolder` class:

```
public class TypesSummaryHolder {
private int with;
private int type;
private int reason1;
private int reason2;
    private int count;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I then created an ArrayList to store the 15000+ instances of `TypesHolder` and another ArrayList to store the `TypesSummaryHolder` objects who represent each of the unique combinations of `width`, `type`, `reason1`, and `reason2` from the `TypesHolder` objects, along with a `count` variable for each of the unique combinations.  I wrote the following code to populate the ArrayList of `TypesSummaryHolder` objects along with their counts:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
static void countCommunicationTypes(){
    int CommunicationWithNumber;int CommunicationTypeNumber;int CommunicationReasonNumber;
    int SecondReasonNumber;int counter = 0;
    ArrayList<EncounterTypesHolder> types = new ArrayList<EncounterTypesHolder>();
    ArrayList<EncounterTypesSummaryHolder> summaries = new ArrayList<EncounterTypesSummaryHolder>();
////////
    try {Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    Connection sourceConn = null;
    try {sourceConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PIC_NEW_32");}
    catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    Statement st = null;
    try {st = sourceConn.createStatement();}
    catch (Exception e1) {  e1.printStackTrace();}
    ResultSet rest = null;
    try {
        rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM someTable");
        while (rest.next()) {
            CommunicationWithNumber = rest.getInt(3);
            CommunicationTypeNumber = rest.getInt(5);
            CommunicationReasonNumber = rest.getInt(6);
            SecondReasonNumber = rest.getInt(6);
            EncounterTypesHolder etype = new EncounterTypesHolder();
            etype.setWith(CommunicationWithNumber);
            etype.setType(CommunicationTypeNumber);
            etype.setReason1(CommunicationReasonNumber);
            etype.setReason2(SecondReasonNumber);
            if(!isDuplicateType(etype,types)){
                EncounterTypesSummaryHolder summaryholder = new EncounterTypesSummaryHolder();
                summaryholder.setWith(CommunicationWithNumber);
                summaryholder.setType(CommunicationTypeNumber);
                summaryholder.setReason1(CommunicationReasonNumber);
                summaryholder.setReason2(SecondReasonNumber);
                summaryholder.setCount(1);
                summaries.add(summaryholder);
            } else {
                EncounterTypesSummaryHolder summaryholder = new EncounterTypesSummaryHolder();
                summaryholder.setWith(etype.getWith());
                summaryholder.setType(etype.getType());
                summaryholder.setReason1(etype.getReason1());
                summaryholder.setReason2(etype.getReason2());
                if(isDuplicateSummaryType(summaryholder, summaries)){
                    for(int u = 0; u<summaries.size();u++){
                        if((CommunicationWithNumber==summaries.get(u).getWith()) && (CommunicationTypeNumber==summaries.get(u).getType()) && (CommunicationReasonNumber==summaries.get(u).getReason1()) && (SecondReasonNumber==summaries.get(u).getReason2()) ){
                            int oldcount = summaries.get(u).getCount();
                            int newcount = oldcount+1;
                            summaries.get(u).setCount(newcount);
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    summaryholder.setCount(1);
                    summaries.add(summaryholder);
                }
            }
            types.add(etype);
            counter += 1;
            System.out.println("counter is: "+counter);
            System.out.println("summaries.size() is: "+summaries.size());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    System.out.println("at end: counter is: "+counter);
    System.out.println("at end: types.size() is: "+types.size());
    System.out.println("at end: summaries.size() is: "+summaries.size());
    int total = 0;
    for(int r=0;r<summaries.size();r++){
        total += summaries.get(r).getCount();
        int with = summaries.get(r).getWith();int type = summaries.get(r).getType();int reason1 = summaries.get(r).getReason1();int reason2 = summaries.get(r).getReason2();int thiscount = summaries.get(r).getCount();
    }
    System.out.println("total is: "+total);
}
static boolean isDuplicateType(EncounterTypesHolder testType, ArrayList<EncounterTypesHolder> types){
    for(int j = 0; j<types.size(); j++){
        if( (testType.getWith() == types.get(j).getWith()) && (testType.getType() == types.get(j).getType())  && (testType.getReason1() == types.get(j).getReason1()) && (testType.getReason2() == types.get(j).getReason2())){
            System.out.println("=====TRUE!!====");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
static boolean isDuplicateSummaryType(EncounterTypesSummaryHolder testType, ArrayList<EncounterTypesSummaryHolder> types){
        for(int j = 0; j<types.size(); j++){
            if( (testType.getWith() == types.get(j).getWith()) && (testType.getType() == types.get(j).getType())  && (testType.getReason1() == types.get(j).getReason1()) && (testType.getReason2() == types.get(j).getReason2())){
                System.out.println("=====TRUE!!====");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

The code above is producing the following SYSO output at the end:

```
at end: counter is: 15415
at end: types.size() is: 15415
at end: summaries.size() is: 15084
total is: 2343089
```

The max possible value for `summaries.size()` should be around 600, but the 331 you get from `types.size()` minus `summaries.size()` above is within the range of believable values for `summaries.size()`.  However, the value for total should be equal to the 15414 value of `types.size()`.  What is wrong with my code above?  How can I change my code above to get both a list of the unique combinations of `with`, `type`, `reason1`, and `reason2`, and also a `count` of the number of instances with each of those unique value combinations?

Comment: What constitutes a "unique type" here?  Is it that all four fields hold a different value?

Comment: @user2338547 A unique type means that the combination of four values is unique. So with 4 variables a, b, c, d, the max number of unique combinations is a x b x c x d, which in my case is around 600. Note that a is number of choices for a, b is number of choices for b, c is number of choices for c, d is number of choices for d.

Comment: OK, see the answer I just put up then.  I think it works

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you could add `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods to to `TypesHolder`, then add all your values to a `Set<TypesHolder>` of some sort.  Then just count the total objects (call `size()`) in the set to get the number of unique combinations.

Here's a link to [implementing `hashcode()` and `equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) from SO, if you're not familiar with those methods.  Google is your friend.

Comment: Oh come on, can you [read the docs?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)  You call `add()` as many times as you read an object, then call `size()` once at the end.

Comment: please do not lose patience.  I read documentation all day long.  people post questions here when they need help they are not understanding from the documentation.

Comment: you did not answer the question yet.  a person could spend a couple days picking through what you sent and still figure out that your approach is wrong.  by contrast, you could spend 1 minutes answering the question in code. I could spend 10 minutes testing your suggestion, and then report back whether or not it works, and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: But if you spend a bit of time learning it now, rather than asking him to write it for you, you'll know how to do it next time something similar comes up.  He gave you a good and pretty simple way to solve the problem, so you have to learn to understand it.  If you have questions about it, post another question and someone will happily help you

Comment: @MarJohnson That is silly.  People learn by seeing working code and dissecting it.  That's the only way people remember the concepts later.  Also, people find these postings for years later through google searches.  Lousy incomplete responses like this one significantly lower the editorial quality of the site.  People who find this from the search engines will want to see working code.  When someone gives working code, I will mark theirs as the answer.